# Defining Multiplication on Strongly Homogeneous Commutative Semigroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples, semigroups

Let us call any commutative semigroup $(S, +)$ strongly homogeneous if it satisfies the following three properties:

P-1. Every endomorphism on $S$ is a bijection.

P-2. Any two endomorphisms on $S$ commute.

P-3. For every $x, y \in S$ there exist one and only one endomorphism $\psi$ on $S$ such that $\psi(x) = y$.

Is the following true?

> Corresponding to any element $1 \in S$ there exist one a̶n̶d̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶  associative binary operation $\times$ satisfying, for all $x,y,z \in S$,

$$\tag 1 1 \times 1 = 1$$

$$\tag 2 x \times y = y \times x$$

$$\tag 3 x \times (y+z) = x \times y + x \times z$$

> Moreover, for every $x \ S$ there exists $y \in S$ with $x \times y = 1$.

**My Work**

I sketched out a proof for a special case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3262239/432081), and I think the argument can be lifted, but I'm not completely confident in using this logic and would like verification/confirmation.

If the theory is false, a counter-example would be appreciated.

Comment: Apart from the empty semigroup and the one-element semigroup, do you know any example of a strongly homogeneous commutative semigroup?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yes - $(\Bbb R^{\gt 0}, 1, +)$.